# How can I create a flattened and concatenated series in jq

Tags: jq

This is the data I have:

```json
[
  {
    "repo": "bar/foo/bat",
    "tags": [
      "0.0.4-22.09"
    ]
  },
  {
    "repo": "thing/foo/baz",
    "tags": [
      "0.0.2-22.09",
      "0.0.3-22.09"
    ]
  }
]
```

And what I want is a flattened list of `repo:tag` for each of these entries

```
"bar/foo/bat:0.0.4-22.09"
"thing/foo/baz:0.0.2-22.09"
"thing/foo/baz:0.0.3-22.09"
```

I am not quite sure how to express this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the field names, just add them together using `+`. Using `[]` on arrays will automatically iterate over their items.

```bash
.[] | .repo + ":" + .tags[]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/su5UxGYe2OM)

If you don't know their names, create an array of arrays of items (getting rid of the objects), and iterate over the inner arrays as above while successively reducing the outer ones, e.g. using `until`:

```bash
.[] | map([.[]? // .]) | until(has(1) | not;
  .[:2] |= [[.[0][] + ":" + .[1][]]]
)[][]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vbADi-e0k8Y)

Output:

```json
"bar/foo/bat:0.0.4-22.09"
"thing/foo/baz:0.0.2-22.09"
"thing/foo/baz:0.0.3-22.09"
```

To output the strings without JSON encoding (~ without quotes), use the `-r` (or `--raw-output`) flag when invoking `jq`.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand how the `+ .tags[]` resolves like this correctly; though obviously, it does. I would have expected all tags appended to 1 repo name. You get the vote but I really want to understand this

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno Generally speaking, if filters produce more than one result, the whole expression is run with each result in place. Using `.tags[]` is such a case if the `.tags` array contains more than one element. The expression (here, addition to `.repo`) is run as many times. Going further: If  `.repo` had also been an array of strings, `.repo[] + ":" + .tags[]` would produce the Cartesian Product (each item from one array combined with each item from the other).